# Vuejs returning data while user typing

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have numeric input field and I'd like to return some results while user is filling the input field.

## code

```
<input type="number" name="bid" v-model="bid.bid" class="form-control">
```

## Logic

1. Users starts to type numbers in field above
2. Will get that number -%10 below it
3. Returned number will change consistently when user changes the input

example:

[image: one]

> PS: The reason that I didn't share any `watch, mounted, etc.` code is
>   because i don't have any code for this question.

any idea?

Comment: You could use a computed property.

Comment: Would you mind share with me how to do it? Ps: is it possible to return with decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the value directly into the page pretty easily using interpolation:

```
<div>You get: {{bid.bid * 0.9}}</div>
```

Comment: I will try this, ps: is it possible to return it with decimals?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. What's important to note is that the syntax `{{ expression }}` will evaluate the JavaScript expression within the double curly braces; however, not all JavaScript will be allowed inside. You could also do `{{ methodName() }}` in order to call a method called `methodName` and insert whatever that method returns. This allows you to use all valid JavaScript within the method body. So one such case could be that you use `{{ formatAsDecimal(bid.bid * 0.9) }}` and simply write the method `formatAsDecimal` such that it formats the input appropriately.

Comment: I have tried your code and it is working perfectly (i accepted then question already) just to know how can I make my input field with decimal? just in appearance but for data saving i still get is as normal numbers? `e.g` user types `1000000` but sees `1.000.000` but when i send data for save to controller still i send it as `1000000`

Comment: That's not a decimal representation. What you're looking for is grouping of digits. You can accomplish this with `bid.bid.toLocaleString()`. For example, for a US English locale (digits separated by commas, e.g. 1000000 -> 1,000,000), you would do `bid.bid.toLocaleString('en-US')`. Simply look up the locale you want and use it instead. Also, for future reference, if you have additional questions that aren't directly related to your original question like this question about number formatting, please submit a new, separate question.

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple snippet. Hope it would be useful.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bid: 0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  your bid: <input type="number" name="bid" v-model.number="bid" class="form-control">
  <br>
  your result: <span>{{bid*0.9}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed property for that :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    bid: 1000
  },
  computed: {
    reducedBid() {
      return this.bid * 0.9
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" name="bid" v-model="bid" class="form-control">
  <p>You get {{ reducedBid }}</p>
</div>
```

Here is a [resource](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) on computed properties.

Hope it helps!